# Not sure what im doing wrong here (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

First I wanna ask the user to enter the weight, then I wanna ask them if their input value is in kg or lbs. If they enter the weight in kg, I wanna output their weight in lbs and vice versa.

```
weight = input('Enter your weight: ')
unite = input('In kg(k) or lbs(l)? ')
k = 2.2046/float(weight)
l = 0.453592*float(weight)

if weight and k:
  print(l ,'lbs')
elif weight and l:
  print(k ,'kg')
```

Heres what I did. Can someone explain why its always showing "lbs" with the output value? Can't seem to get it to show "kg" when I initially choose (l), but the conversion is fine

Answer (score 0):

Its always showing "lbs" because the first condition is always true.

```
if weight and k:
```

It just checks whether both weight and k value is exist or not if both value exist it will execute the if condition.

so change the condition to:

```
if weight and unite=='k':
  print(l ,'lbs')
elif weight and unite=='l':
  print(k ,'kg')
```

check out this code:

```
weight = input('Enter your weight: ')
unite = input('In kg(k) or lbs(l)? ').strip()
k = 2.2046/float(weight)
l = 0.453592*float(weight)
if weight and unite=='k':
  print(l ,'lbs')
elif weight and unite=='l':
  print(k ,'kg')
```

if the user gives space while providing input it will not work.So I have used strip() to remove space.

```
 unite = input('In kg(k) or lbs(l)? ').strip()
```